# MySQL duplicate entry for key in CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table which works with a paired unique index, which is (building_id, group_id). The schema must not change, so I have to find a way to overpass the following restriction which occurs when I want to swap buildings between groups. We have the entries (building, building) 1-1 and 1-2 for the unique index. If I use:

```
UPDATE table SET group_id=
CASE group_id
WHEN 1 THEN 2
WHEN 2 THEN 1
ELSE group_id
END
```

The (reasonable) error I'm getting is "Duplicate entry '1-2' for key...". Of course, one naive way is to set both to max(group_id)+1 and +2, and then change the back to their final id, but as this is going to affect huge number of rows, I'm trying to avoid the double update for the means of performance.

Regards,
Orestes.

Comment: If you can't drop the index or and recreate it after the update or at least disable it, then two updates is the only way to go.

Comment: you might be able to disable the unique index with something like    SET unique_checks=0;    just make sure to re-enable it when you are done

Comment: Great idea, it didn't cross my silly mind! Thank you for your time and help (both of you). If I choose to switch off and on the indexing, of course I have to expect an error if the input causes duplicates. So I have to handle such validation in the part before the update. Thank you very much!